# Command line tool for merging fonts files

Tags: command-line, font-utility, file-merging, merge

I need to merge hundreds of .ttf fonts *(OpenType and TrueType)*.
Many Tells about fontforge, but it use a gui interface, so I would need to merge each fonts manually.

So, is there a command-line tool for merging fonts so I can use simple bash glob?

Comment: You refer to a 'bash blog', which is typically for unix and linux, but has been ported to other OS as well.  For which OS do you need this tool?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard : I don't mind about the OS.

Comment: Which implies that if you are using Windows then you are happy to install Cygwin, just to get bash? Or is the mention of bash in the question misleading?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard : It can't work like this because there are metadata inside ttf file which include pointers.

Comment: @Mawg : No, bash alone is irrelevant here. but CMD or powershell can work. Also **ARRRGHHH for Cygwin** : building an API over WIN32 *(or WIN64 now)* when [WIN32 is itself a subsystem](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/en-uk/library/cc767884.aspx). Take SUA, it will offer far more performance. But in my case I can take darwin as well as android.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the merge.  If the fonts are compatible in certain ways but have different scripts in them, then my merge script might work:

https://github.com/behdad/fonttools/blob/master/Tools/pyftmerge

If you tell us what kind of usecase you have, we might be able to help you.  Let us know here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fonttools

Comment: As I said on IRC I want to merge fonts families *(ex :`fontRegular.ttf + fontItalic.ttf + fontBold.ttf = font.ttf`)*.